# Numpy dstack for 3d arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have N 3d arrays, with fixed sizes (n1, n2, n3)
Now I want to combine them into 4d array and as the result to have array of the dimension:

(N, n1, n2, n3)

How should I do it? Dstack is doing the same thing but only for 2D arrays making them 3D. Trying to make it for 3D array gives wrong results (n1, n2, n3*N)

**EDIT 1:** I need to do it in the loop, so each iteration in the loop gives new (n1, n2, n3) array (3d array) which I should to put into 4D array increasing it's first dimension: 1st iteration would give (1, n1, n2, n3)

then 2nd iteration would give (2, n1, n2, n3) and so on.

Comment: Look at the code for these various `stack` functions.  All they do is tweak the dimensions of the input arrays, and then use `np.concatenate`.  If you get the dimensions right you too can use `np.concatenate` directly (preferably with a list of all the arrays).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dstack` only exists for backwards compatibility. Use [`numpy.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack) instead, which is more generic and future proof:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((4, 5, 6))
b = np.zeros((4, 5, 6))

c = np.stack([a, b])
print(c.shape)  # (2, 4, 5, 6)

d = np.stack([a, b], axis=2)  # You can stack along any axis
print(d.shape)  # (4, 5, 2, 6)
```

Loopy example:

```
result = []
for i in range(n):
    x = np.random.randn(n1, n2, n3)
    result.append(x)
result = np.stack(result)
```

Alternative (slower):

```
result = np.empty((0, n1, n2, n3))
for i in range(n):
    x = np.random.randn(n1, n2, n3)
    result = np.concatenate([result, x[np.newaxis]])
```

You can also preallocate if you know N in advance:

```
result = np.empty((n, n1, n2, n3))
for i in range(n):
    x = np.random.randn(n1, n2, n3)
    result[i] = x
```

Comment: Sorry, just edited my question with additional info. Your way works great though only for one iteration, next iteration would try to stack 4D with 3D.

Comment: In a loop I would usually append the 3d arrays to a list and call `stack` on that list after the loop is done. (See updated example.) This has better performance than growing the array because it avoids reallocation.